# Using routes to change page name and extension

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm porting an old WebForms application to .NET Core Razor Pages.

I have a few cases where I'd like to retain the old URLs. I have a Razor Page called *Resources/CharClass*, but I'd like the URL to be *Resources/CharClass.aspx*.

I tried the following, but it doesn't route to the desired page.

```
@page "{title=CharClass.aspx}"
@model TestRazorPages.Pages.Resources.CharClassModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CharClass";
}

<h1>CharClass</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is to add a route data parameter placeholder and given it a default value, rather than create a new route (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-templates).

In your `ConfigureServices` method in `StartUp`, add the following in Razor Pages 2.2:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Resources/CharClass", "/Resources/Charclass.aspx");
});
```

If you are using .NET 3.0, chain the call to `AddRazorPagesOptions` to `services.AddRazorPages()`

More about the additive routes here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#friendly-routes

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Razor Pages. Do you know if there's a way to instead do a 301 redirect without creating a separate page for the redirect?

Comment: You could use middleware for that: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/middleware. In the Invoke method, check Request.Path and redirect accordingly, setting the HTTP status accordingly and the location header.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the old route? I struggled with that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72843642/9971404).