# Change URL of Razor Class Library page from client project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-routing

I created a Razor [Class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (v6). In the RCL I have a page at `~/Pages/Page1.cshtml`, which is accessible at `/Page1`.

But the RCL is for use in other projects, so I want a *client project* to be able to customise the path.

For example, how can a client project change that to `/Foo/Page1`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working but NON-IDEAL solution.

In the client project:

```cs
services.AddMyRclProject("/Foo/Page1");
```

In the RCL project:

```cs
public static void AddMyRclProject(this IServiceCollection services, string customRoute){

  services.AddRazorPages(x => {
    x.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Page1", customRoute);
  });

}
```

This works, but both routes are active:

```
/Page1
/Foo/Page1
```

It's unclear how to remove the original one.

**I'm leaving this question open. If you have a better way, add your answer and I'll accept it.**